# Unity 3D Double Jump C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey guys I had tried to program double Jump for my 3d First Person shooter game. It kind of works but not as expected. If I hit space the player jumps the height of 800, but it is supposed to jump 500 and if you hit space again 300. Can somebody please help me?

```
void Start()
{
    rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    //Keys
    bool jump = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);

    //Statics
    bool isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundDetector.position, 0.1f, ground);
    bool isJumping = jump && isGrounded;
    bool isSneaking = sneak;
    bool isSliding = !isSneaking && slide && !slideing && !slideStop && isGrounded;

    if (isGrounded)
    {
        print("vallah");
        jumpCount = 0;
    }

    //Jump
    if (isJumping && isGrounded && !isSliding && !isSneaking)
    {
        rig.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
        jumpCount++;

        if (jumpCount > 0 && jumpCount < 2 && jump)
        {
            rig.AddForce(Vector3.up * secondJunp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the last if statement to handle the jump count:

```
if (isJumping && (jumpCount <= 2) && !isSliding && !isSneaking)// HERE <--
{
    // Increase Jump Count
    jumpCount++;

    // First check the jump number
    if (jumpCount == 1)
    {
        rig.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
    }
     else if (jumpCount == 2)
    {
        rig.AddForce(Vector3.up * secondJunp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. It worked out so big thank you.